# Is it posible to restart my DIscordBot with one click in the Console?

Tags: node.js, discord.js

Is it possible to detect and click in the Console
Example :
I click X and it restarts my DiscordBot Code

My Current start.bat

```
@echo off
echo Starting..
:main
node index.js
echo Restarting!
goto main
```

Answer (score 1):

I think better use [pm2](https://pm2.keymetrics.io/docs/usage/quick-start/) For management your bot. In **pm2** you can use commands like `restart appname`
`start appname`, and sure its possible run with `.bat` file.

Comment: I know how to restart it with Commands...
My Question was is it possible to restart it with just one Click

Comment: In which console?

Comment: In my .bat console like while its running i just click X and it restarts

Comment: Ubunty, Linux, MacOS ?